# DKIM for Mandrill on Amazon's Route 53

Tags: email, dns, mandrill, amazon-route53, dkim

I am trying to set up a DKIM record on Amazon's Route 53. I just choose to add TXT record with  name like this: mandrill._domainkey.domain.com

and the value is:

"v=DKIM1; k=rsa;
p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrLHiExVd55zd/IQ/J/mRwSRMAocV/hMB3jXwaHH36d9NaVynQFYV8NaWi69c1veUtRzGt7yAioXqLj7Z4TeEUoOLgrKsn8YnckGs9i3B3tVFB+Ch/4mPhXWiNfNdynHWBcPcbJ8kjEQ2U8y78dHZj1YeRXXVvWob2OaKynO8/lQIDAQAB;"

but Route 53 keeps complaining about:

The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only had to delete all new lines and it worked!

for example this works ... notice the big double quotes text is now several smaller quoted strings

```
"v=DKIM1;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAm1MmXbj57e""dW5nN1Yi6SxLBa+n4DcMTL8+fbhqarL0PRlzlriOtxWmqZzKlkoh9I0eBXgSNj2g""pUUl32fEirdf2KM7ZAxbvJohn1P/18I3lr65CjQGPm5iljIVQFPpUzwepbVt""frg/MjJtMkE2JeSs03TBTtCkthepQrV/tmMVoqycOhp32LklGtqfl/eYNnjFDPt5""ID0FZMlXucdkMl4fapi66edKKAbK0RLgOZ19uE2EdGkU+lDaVVcBdJ9omTnTf2kq""4zdZ9K+PG7GJO0vyRSIzyCMGnAmEkgyTFEBh7+hrVKapr71o6/y3eXtYToQiC5qP""1vX6u7o6kkd/Bi7QIDAQAB"
```

Notice I had to transform a very long string into a series of smaller strings

original :

```
"this is sample very long string alaalal bblblbbl ckckcck "
```

what works :

```
"this is sample very"" long string alaa""lal bblblbbl ckckcck "
```