# DKIM and DMARC problems with Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, dkim, dmarc

**DKIM Problem:**

Here is how I enter the value for DKIM key:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=JKskfkkSLLWOFJDJFKKSLLFOxsnnisn/SnhcQp2oP1RKDYd6AdmpYf2y+0O/OayDhhLCMRHB+A3F4cYp01wXk2BF6OMuqUKGRh/5a1d8fKpW5vSCpZWf2i8rwXU0Aae11Kku742IxnPXLQFP/OUjNyWi3pZV7E6hShsKDs3Fks67Kslwoo,s+fw8z0ROCGZ9NNUQmTVf4bBmB919mrnv" "KP2n9zX3n2mty/fqv8AEWGUlMyg0EjKJtpEAt6ApdlWlfk43123m5K0UhWRH8Gf0f/v8orSwkksbmHoXX/5x7J999/EUWo+fSVjskiwk23gFcohutk85/7u4w1E9gmdnRX6C7J/Ay8fwIDAQAB"
```

When I try to add it AWS doesn't acceppt it because it is too long.

I came across the below post on Stackoverflow where commenters advised that I should break break up the string with (""):

[DKIM for Mandrill on Amazon's Route 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363640/dkim-for-mandrill-on-amazons-route-53)

So I followed the advice and did the following:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhki""G9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAthZaOcxMzOmiQx""Aw7p/SnhcQp2oP1RKDYd6AdmpYf2y+0O/Oa""yDhhLCMRHB+A3F4cYp01wXk2BF6OMuqUKGRh/5a1d8""fKpW5vSCpZWf2i8rwXU0Aae11Kku742Ix""nPXLQFP/OUjNytrytrZV7E6jlkjWkjpOETcJpeWcU34VXvRRzQQ""q+fw8z0ROCGZ9NNUQmTVf4bBmB919mrnvKP2""n9zX3n2mty/fqv8AEWGUlMy""g0EjKJtpEAt6jlkjApRg1TYdzA4m5K0""UhWRH8Gf0f/v8orS27bm""HoXX/5x7J999/EUWo+fSV0TUv""0gFtrtyeutk85/7u4w1E9""gmdnRX6C7J/Ay8fwIDAQAB"
```

However I am still getting a DKIM fail,according to https://dmarcian.com/dkim-validator/, my Record is not formatted correctly and Public key ("p" tag) is required. I am copying and pasting directly from the terminal so I have no idea what I am doing wrong?

Furthermore, when I do a dig I receive DKIM TXT however I see gaps in where I put the apostrophes. Not sure if this is causing my problem?

I also looked at https://serverfault.com/questions/763815/route-53-doesnt-allow-adding-dkim-keys-because-length-is-too-long.

However I still get the same issues, I aslo read that doing /"/" should help, so I tried:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhki""G9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAthZaOcxMzOmiQx/"/"Aw7p/SnhcQp2oP1RKDYd6AdmpYf2y+0O/Oa""yDhhLCMRHB+A3F4cYp01wXk2BF6OMuqUKGRh/5a1d8"/"/fKpW5vSCpZWf2i8rwXUytut11Kku742Ix""nPXLQFP/OUjNiuyiu3pZV7E6hShWkjpOETcJpeWcU34VXvRRzQQ"/"/q+fw8z0ROCGghfhgfhNNUQmTVf4bBmB919mrnvKP2"/"/n9zX3n2mty/fqv8AEWGUlMy"/"/g0EjKJtpEAt68DpApRg1TYdzA4m5K0"/"/UhWRH8Gf0f/v8orS27bm"/"/HoXX/5x7J999/EUWo+fSV0TUv"/"/0grytstk85/7u4w1E9""gmdnRX6C7J/Ay8fwIDAQAB"
```

But once again I get the string is too long and I am unable to save the record... I am totally lost on what to do. I have never had such a problem setting up DKIM before.

**DMARC Issue**

I have set up a TXT record for DMARC such as below for mailserver, _demarc.mydomain.co.za:

```
"v=DMARC1; p=reject;"
```

When I assess the mails, there is no DMARC? I have added it correctly according to the documentation but it doesn't work?

What the heck am I doing wrong? All I can say is first and last time

I will use Route53 again, its been a horrible experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to your origin entry, and note what the Route 53 console says when you create a `TXT` record:

```
A text record. Enter multiple values
    on separate lines. Enclose text in
    quotation marks.
Example:
    "Sample Text Entries"
    "Enclose entries in quotation marks"
```

When you paste your long value in the text box, it will *appear* correct because your browser is breaking the space at `...9mrnv"<HERE>"KP2n...` and showing two lines, but it is wrong. Deleting the space is also wrong, but delete that space and hit enter and you can save the record.

You need *exactly* these two lines with a line break between them (not a space expanded into a break) in the box:

```
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=JKskfkkSLLWOFJDJFKKSLLFOxsnnisn/SnhcQp2oP1RKDYd6AdmpYf2y+0O/OayDhhLCMRHB+A3F4cYp01wXk2BF6OMuqUKGRh/5a1d8fKpW5vSCpZWf2i8rwXU0Aae11Kku742IxnPXLQFP/OUjNyWi3pZV7E6hShsKDs3Fks67Kslwoo,s+fw8z0ROCGZ9NNUQmTVf4bBmB919mrnv"
"KP2n9zX3n2mty/fqv8AEWGUlMyg0EjKJtpEAt6ApdlWlfk43123m5K0UhWRH8Gf0f/v8orSwkksbmHoXX/5x7J999/EUWo+fSVjskiwk23gFcohutk85/7u4w1E9gmdnRX6C7J/Ay8fwIDAQAB"
```

Tested in the Route 53 console.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works because Route53 has changed - tested today using [Hacktisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66914983) using single line without spaces or line breaks between double quoted strings.  dmarcian.com validates this DKIM record.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE APRIL 2021:**

It seems that Route53 has changed since the accepted answer was posted. The only way I managed to make my DKIM valid was by having **no line break** (and no space) between the chunks.

Example record:
*TXT [selector]._domainkey*
`"v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=MII.....""....SKFKFDAB"`

Comment: This is the correct method according to this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-resolve-dkim-text-record-error/

Comment: This works, tested today - see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885953/dkim-and-dmarc-problems-with-route53#comment137335352_58887107)

Answer (score 2):

AWS posted a tutorial on how to solve this issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-resolve-dkim-text-record-error/

In essence:

- Make it 2 chunks of length < 254
- Enclose the chunks in double quotes.
- Use NO line breaks between them when pasting the value in Route53's record editor.